# how to enable remote access to a MySQL server on an AZURE virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, azure, mysql5

I have an AZURE virtual machine with a MySQL server installed on it running ubuntu 13.04.  I am trying to remote connect to the MySQL server however get the simple error "Can't connect to MySQL server on {IP}"

I have already done the follow:

```
* commented out the bind-address within the /etc/mysql/my.cnf
* commented out skip-external-locking within the same my.cnf
* "ufw allow mysql"
* "iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT"
* setup an AZURE endpoint for mysql
* "sudo netstat -lpn | grep 3306" does indeed show mysql LISTENING
* "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO remote@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
* "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO remote@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
* "/etc/init.d/mysql restart"
* I can connect via SSH tunneling, but not without it
* I have spun up an identical ubuntu 13.04 server on rackspace and SUCCESSFULLY connected using the same procedures outlined here.
```

NONE of the above works on my azure server however.  I thought the creation of an endpoint would work, but no luck.  Any help please?  Is there something I'm missing entirely?

[image]

Comment: What is the error you receive when connecting to the MySQL server?

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (60)

Comment: Try disabling Direct Server return.

Comment: Here is official manual for Azure VM: [manual](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/02/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/)

Answer (score 3):

The 'official manual' quoted above didnt work for me and seems to set up a ssh tunnel to accomplish this... even after following the guide it still didnt work.

Heres my working solution

For a Ubuntu Azure VM see:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-lamp-stack/

Specifically the section "Allow remote access to MySQL"

Comment out:

```
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf

run

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

and my remote connections worked --- just make sure port 3306 is open in the azure server portal for your vm!

Comment: I had to reboot my Azure machine before I could get the port opened.  I'm not sure if it was a problem with the Azure firewall or with mariadb not wanting to read the config file on reboot.

Comment: In my vm, this line was in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf` file.

Comment: Link you provided is dead :(

Comment: Is it dangerous to open port `3306` in the azure server?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/) succinct guide was useful for me to get mine to work.

While there are other essential steps [that I had already done] there, the one I was missing was this:

3306 port is not opened by default, hence you need to first open this port so a remote client can connect to your MySQL Server. Run the following command to open TCP port 3306:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

check if the port 3306 is open by running this command:

```
sudo netstat -anltp|grep :3306
```

Answer (score -2):

Check your firewall uring sudo ufw status.

Comment: The OP already did that.